# Reading a file and check whether the lines end with semicolon

Tags: java

I read a text file which contains the following code.

```
void main()
{
    int A = 5 ;
    float B = 6 
    double C ; 
    C = A + B ;
    cout << C ; 
}
```

I wanted to loop through the lines of code and check if each line ends with a semicolon(;).

I wrote the following code and ran it on NetBeans IDE.

```
int lineCount = 0;

BufferedReader ReadFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\ReadFile2.txt"));

while ((CurrentLine = ReadFile.readLine()) != null)
{
    lineCount++;
    if (CurrentLine.endsWith(";"))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        jTextArea2.append("Error at line" + " " + lineCount);                   
    }

}
```

After running the code, the output wasn't as it suppose to be.
This was the output

```
Error at line 1 
Error at line 2
Error at line 4 
Error at line 5 
Error at line 7
Error at line 8
```

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions: Start your variable names with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line you are reading has probably some spaces after the `;`, try this:

```
if (CurrentLine.trim().endsWith(";"))
```

Comment: @Lonerli You are welcome! Make sure to 'tick' it when SO lets you do that!

Comment: What if I don't want it check the first, second and the last line which doesn't has to end with a semicolon?

Comment: @Lonerli i think the best way to do it is using a regex. because theoretically after `()` there should be a `;`, but in fact if `()` is followed by a `{` it is correct, and you should check it with a regex